# Google Stepped Area Chart bug with first step

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I was trying to build a **Stepped Area** google chart but I always get a bug with the first step not appearing...

This is my code

```
function drawChart() {
      // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('date', 'formatedDate');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data.addRows([
          [new Date(1576022400000), 3],
          [new Date(1576026000000), 1],
          [new Date(1576029600000), 1],
          [new Date(1576033200000), 1],
          [new Date(1576036800000), 2]
        ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.SteppedAreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
```

Here is an example of the bug: https://jsfiddle.net/hm37Lyf9/1/

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

according to the [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/steppedareachart#data-format) for a stepped area chart,
the first column, or x-axis column, should be a string.
since a date is being used, this is most likely the problem.

see following working snippet,
here, a data view is used,
which has a calculated column that converts the date to a time string.

as such, the first step is displayed.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  // Create the data table.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'datatat');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
  data.addRows([
    [new Date(1576022400000), 3],
    [new Date(1576026000000), 1],
    [new Date(1576029600000), 1],
    [new Date(1576033200000), 1],
    [new Date(1576036800000), 2]
  ]);

  // Create a date formatter
  var formatDate = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
    pattern: 'HH:ss a'
  });

  // Create a data view, with calculated column for time string
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([{
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      return formatDate.formatValue(dt.getValue(row, 0));
    },
    label: data.getColumnLabel(0),
    type: 'string'
  }, 1]);

  // Set chart options
  var options = {
    title: 'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
    width: 400,
    height: 300
  };

  // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
  var chart = new google.visualization.SteppedAreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  // Draw chart with data view
  chart.draw(view, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```